# react const contains undefined after setState with useImmer

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to move my propsValue into new array.

There are 2 buttons in my codes, first button(Convert them) executes the transfer.
second button(print All) prints every key and value of Users

however, my "print all" button prints undefined after the transfer.

How should I modify my codes to contain correct values?

Thank you

```
import React from 'react';
import { useImmer } from "use-immer";
const UserImmer = () => {
  const propsValue = [
    {
      value: "Name", key:"first_name"
    },
    {
      value: "last Name", key:"last_name"
    },
    {
      value: "E mail", key:"e_mail"
    },
    {
      value: "Address", key: "address"
    }
  ]

  const [user, setUser] = useImmer({
    value: '',
    key: '',
  })
  const [users, setUsers] = useImmer([])

  const onbuttonChange = () => {
    //iteration begins
    const name = "HAHA2";
    propsValue.map(data =>  (
       
       console.log("Iteration : ", data.value, " : ", data.key),
       
       //save propsValue into user one by one
       setUser(draft => {
            draft.value =  data.value;
            draft.key = data.key;
          }),

          //push user into Users
          //
          setUsers(draft => {
            draft.push(user);
          }),

          //initialize the user
        setUser(draft => {
            draft.value = "";
            draft.key = "";
        })
    ))
  }
  const onClickUser = () => {
    //prints final result of Users but it prtins four undefined
    users.map(temp => console.log("THe Users: ", temp.value, " : " , temp.key));
  }
  return (
    <div>
      
      <button onClick={onClickUser}>print All</button>
      <button onClick={onbuttonChange}>Convert them</button>
    </div>
  )
}
export default UserImmer;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are multiple things that is wrong with this.

1st. The reason its `undefined` is because you are trying to display a data it does not have. You want to display property `name` via `temp.name` in your `console.log("THe Users: ", temp.name, " : ", temp.key))` But look at the object struture - it has no property `name`. it has `value` and `key`. So this is first issue.

2nd. The variable `user`, from the hook, updates AFTER all of the `map` and re-renders. Meaning, the entire time inside the `map`, the `user` remains the default `user` data aka empty. Hooks should be used when it is required to re-render the component after the data change. Hence should just create a variable instead of using a hook.

```
let user = {
  value: "",
  key: ""
};
```

and instead of `setUser` just

```
(user = data),
```

If you wish so it would be changed from `value` to `name` the simpliest way

```
(user = {
  name: data.value,
  key: data.key
}),
```

or better yet - REMOVE THE USER! It serves no purpose. the data is the same. It has no extra funcionality rather then taking up resources.

3rd. The push does not work.

```
    setUsers((draft) => {
      draft.push(user);
    })
```

You can change it to `users.push(user)` but then the `users` cant be a hook either. Hence when it changes it will not re-render the component. In your case - its fine since the data is only being showed AFTER another button click. But if you wish to display the data without clicking the `print` button but asap when you add data to it then you need to use a hook so it re-renders. For that create a new array to store all 'user' and at the end of `map` run `setUsers` by passing the array. This way the component will not have to re-render a bunch of times.

Also, `map` should return something. in your case `propsValue.map` returns nothing. I remade your code by fixing these 3 things: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigorous-rubin-hh7t9?file=/src/App.js . It works as you intended.

P.s. This can also be achieved without using `use-immer`. A simple react `useState` does the same in your case.

Comment: Thank you for the tip. modified temp.name --> temp.value

Comment: but still it prints nothing on my screen

Comment: @JinPark I updated my post. I described the other issues and how to fix em. Hope it helps

Comment: @JinPark if in some cases I miss-understood ur goal, for example with the `user`, or if you dont understand my explanations then feel free to commend. Ill try to answer it as well as I can.

Comment: Wow awesome, this is the most wonderful advice that I received in stackoverflow. really appreciate your advices  Thank you